# Visual Studio 2019 Python Breakpoint Not Hit

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints

I started a new Python 3.8 project in Visual Studio 2019.  I created a virtual environment for the project.  I placed a breakpoint on a line and started the debugger.  While it was debugging, the debugger didn't stop on the breakpoint, and the tooltip on the breakpoint flashed the following message:

*The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint in file excluded by filters.
Note: May be excluded by because of "justMyCode" option (default == true). Try setting "justMyCode": false in the debug configuration (e.g. launch.json)*

My project doesn't even have a launch.json.  I found a "Just my code" option in the settings and it was already set to false.

Any idea why it won't stop on the breakpoint?

Comment: Do you have that problem with every breakpoint (wherever you put it), or just sometimes? If only sometimes, can you say when?

Comment: Are you sure the Python file is a part of your startup project? How are you adding it to the project, as well as building and running the project?

Comment: zvone: It happens wherever I put it

Comment: Random Davis: Yes, I can confirm that the python file is part of my startup project.  I just press the start button and my solution configurations is set to Debug.

Comment: @jgriffo1, try to reset vs settings under Tools-->Import and Export Settings-->Reset all settings 2) close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder and then restart your project.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, will that effect all of my other settings?

Comment: @jgriffo1, it will not affect the used settings and it is equivalent of refresh your project. If you still worry about this, you could make a backup of your project.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I tried this fix, but it didn't work. One slight difference is my breakpoint tooltip doesn't mention filters. "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" The Python interpreter does have symbols loaded.